# Php/iis server sql database error/problem

Tags: php, windows, sqlite, iis, server

I run an IIS. PHP website on a windows server 2016, a good friend has helped me setup a website with a sqlite database. Sadly that database isnt in the same folder as INETPUB is there a way to give IIS acces to folders outside of inetpub? In the same folder it worked perfectly but i need it in a other folder. This is the code:

```
<?php
    //define PDO - tell about the database file
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:C:/TCAFiles/Users/admin/3/garrysmod/sv.db');
    //write SQL
    $statement = $pdo->query("SELECT szMap, szPlayer, nTime, nStyle FROM game_times");
    //run the SQL
    $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //show it on the screen
?>
```

This is the error it gives in the browser:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php(3): PDO->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 3
```

I hope that someone can help me. I have tried this on the localhost from xampp to and that worked correctly

Comment: Does the IIS user have read/write permission to the new folder?

Comment: First, you need to set permissions for the new folder and grant users read and write permissions for this folder. And then ensure that the identity of the application pool where the application is located has sufficient read and write permissions.You can try to modify it to localsystem, localsystem has the highest authority.